# Guardar listas en base de datos DJANGO

Tags: python, sql, base-de-datos, django, sqlite3

Estoy creando un ecommerce en Django. Me surge una pregunta que llevo horas intentando resolver...
Mi tabla Pedidos tiene como columnas: IdPedido, IdCliente, Estado, ListaDeProductos, DescuentoAplicado, Subtotal, Total

Mi idea es almacenar ListaDeProductos de la siguiente manera [(IdProducto, Cantidad), (IdProducto, Cantidad), ... , (IdProducto, Cantidad)]

Mi problema no es almacenar todos los productos comprados en la lista sino el trabajo que hay que hacer para luego leer los productos comprados de cada factura... En serio hay que hacer un scraper del texto almacenado en ListaDeProductos leyendo carácter por carácter para ver cuando hay un símbolo que indique que cambia de IdProducto a Unidades y luego a otro producto...???

Por lo que he visto no se pueden guardar objetos en Django... Alguna idea???

Gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 0):

Cambiando el motor de base de datos a `PostgreSQL`, puedes utilizar el `ArrayField` por el cual puedes almacenar listas.
Ejemplo:

```
Pedidos.objects.create(name='Pepito', productos=['thoughts', 'django'])
```

Te paso el link de la documentación, así hacemos referencia a la versión y a los ejemplos oficiales. Se trata de un `model field` relativamente nuevo.

[Declaracion de campo array](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField)

[Consultas de un campo array](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield)

Si necesitas mas complejidad tambien podrías utilizar [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) , nuevo desde `Django 3.1`